# ansible: how to extract IPs from a list of IPs in the inventory file

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible invetory file with 1 group with 3 IPs listed.

```
[servers]
server-0 ansible_host=10.255.31.7
server-1 ansible_host=10.255.31.9
server-2 ansible_host=10.255.31.8
```

I want to be able to set a variable that only has the 1st 2 IPs

I've been able to set a variable with all 3 using

```
seeds: "{{ hostvars.values()|map(attribute='ansible_host')|join(',') }}"
```

which results in

```
10.255.31.7,10.255.31.9,10.255.31.8
```

But I don't want all 3 IPs, I only want the first 2
which should be

```
10.255.31.7,10.255.31.8
```

I have not been able to figure it out yet, hoping someone can help. Thanks

I've tried several things all to no avail

I'm expecting the IP list to be 10.255.31.7,10.255.31.8

Comment: `hostvars.values()|map(attribute='ansible_host')[:2]|join(',')`, using [python slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing/509295#509295)